# Get Color from resource id integer gives error

Tags: android, android-view, android-resources, android-context

I have created a custom view which accepts background color resid and shadow color resId. But when i convert resource ids to store them in a int variable. It give error as

```
Expected a color resource id (R.color.) but received an RGB integer
```

Following are my setter methods

```
    @Override
    public void setBackgroundColor(@ColorRes int backgroundResId) {
        this.backgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, backgroundResId);
    }

    public void setShadowColor(@ColorRes int shadowColorId) {
        this.shadowColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, shadowColorId);
    }
```

Same error is shown when used

```
public void setBackgroundColor(@ColorRes int backgroundResId) {
    this.backgroundColor = context.getResources().getColor(backgroundResId);
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what is passed as "backgroundResId" please?

Comment: can u share the code where you are calling `setBackgroundColor()` method

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you pass wrong argument in your method `setBackgroundColor`. You should use it in that way:

```
//some code
setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
//some code
```

Comment: `getColor` is deprecated